# Can a $6\times6$ all positive entry matrix have eigenvalues of $\{-1,1,-8,2,6,7\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there any $6\times 6$ real square matrix $A$, all of whose entries are positive with the eigenvalues of $\{-1,1,-8,2,6,7\}$?

I am thinking it is related to the trace, determinant, or similar matrices but I am having trouble getting further.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, by the [Perron-Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) theorem. In fact, the spectral radius of a positive matrix is always an eigenvalue of the matrix.

In your case, the matrix has spectral radius 8, that is not an eigenvalue.